# Android Studio not allowing to open any source file

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using following configuration which was working fine until I downloaded NDK 1.17 for one of project requuirement and it showing following error. Please check snap.

Any suggestion what is possible issue ?

> High number of internal exceptions has been detected. This indicates a
> serious problem with the IDE. Please consider clean reinstall of
> Android Studio. If the problem persists, please report a bug by
> following the link below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem yesterday. I would suggest you to look at you idea.log file (Help > Show Log in Finder / Explorer). This will give you an idea of where it is crashing. In my case, I had an older plugin. After updating that particular plugin, my IDE was working normally. So the idea.log file will tell you where it is failing and will give you a better clue. Hope this helps and please give an up vote. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have any Plugin installed and it is not working with any new update of Studio. then you have to uninstall the previous plugin and then try to rebuild it

**Steps to be follow**

1. Close the Android Studio.
2. On Welcome Screen of Project Selection click on Configuration option
3. Now Select Plugin
4. Uninstall the previous plugin 5.
5. Now try to relaunch the Studio (It's working fine.)
   **

---